# Jenkins how to catch error in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, jenkins

What I am trying to do is once source .... command is executed if there is an error I want to put it into temp file. I tried several ways but no luck.

```
    def responseValue = sh(script: """#!/bin/bash
    set +x
    source /etc/runScript.sh> /dev/null 2>&1 >temp.txt
    echo \${${someVar}}
    """, returnStdout: true)
     def foundValue =  readFile(file: "temp.txt").trim()
     echo "value is ${foundValue}"
     //also tried source /etc/runScript.sh  2>&1> /dev/null >temp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of redirection matters.

```
source /etc/runScript.sh> /dev/null 2>&1 >temp.txt
```

`>/dev/null` redirects standard output to the bit bucket.

`2>&1` redirects standard error to the same as standard output, also to the bit bucket.

`>temp.txt` redirects standard output to the file `temp.txt`, leaving standard error directed to the bit bucket.

I think a safe way to accomplish your goal would be to save each stream to a different file.

```
source /etc/runScript.sh >/dev/null 2>temp.txt
```

Which will send the standard output to `/dev/null` and save the standard error in `temp.txt`.